# how to duplicate same model in react-three-fiber

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

```
import { Stats,OrbitControls,Circle } from '@react-three/drei'
import { Canvas,useLoader } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader'



export default function App() {
    const gltf = useLoader(GLTFLoader,'./models/monkey.glb')
    return (
        <Canvas camera={{ position: [-0.5,1,2] }} shadows>

            <directionalLight position={[3.3,1.0,4.4]} castShadow />
            <primitive
                object={gltf.scene}
                position={[0,1,0]} />

            <primitive
                object={gltf.scene}
                position={[0,1,0]} />
            <Circle args={[10]} rotation-x={-Math.PI / 2} receiveShadow>
                <meshStandardMaterial />
            </Circle>
            <OrbitControls target={[0,0,0]} />
            <axesHelper args={[5]} />
            <Stats />
        </Canvas>
    )
}
```

so I want to insert a model and want to copy it to 2, so I add 2 primitives but can't, is there any other way to duplicate the same model to 2?